# How many numbers between 1-10000 can be divided by 2 and 5 but are not divisible by 3 or 4

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inclusion-exclusion

First i calculated how many numbers are divisible by 2 and 5

$\frac{10000}{2}+\frac{10000}{5}-\frac{10000}{2*5}=6000$

Then i calculated how many numbers are not divisible by 3 or 4

$10000-(\frac{10000}{3}+\frac{10000}{4}-\frac{10000}{3*4})=5000 $

Now i do not know if these steps are correct or even necessary, but i do not know how to get the final result.

Thanks!

Comment: One way is to look at all the possible residues $\bmod 60$. Another way is to use the chinese remainder theorem to count and then just check the last $20$ classes $\bmod 60$.

Comment: $6000$ is the number of numbers divisible by $2$ _or_ $5$. The number of numbers divisible by $2$ _and_ $5$ is simply the number of numbers divisible by $10$.

Comment: As for "*I do not know if these results are correct*" You forgot to include floor functions on your ratios.  They balanced each other out in this case, but that won't always happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are divisible by $2$ and $5$  ,then these numbers can be divided by $10$. So how many numbers are there $[1,10000]$ divisible by $10$ . ?

Answer can be found by Gauss formula such that $\frac{10000-10}{10} + 1 =1000$.

Now assume that our universal set is consisted of these $1000$ numbers . Then , we should eliminate those which are not divisible by $3$ or $4$.

Divisible by $10$ but not $3$ : Divisible by $10$ - (divisible $3$ and $10$) = Divisible by $10$ divisible by $30$ = $1000 - \frac{9990 - 30}{30} + 1 =1000-333=667$

Divisible by $10$ but not $4$ : Divisible by $10$ - (divisible $4$ and $10$) = Divisible by $10$ divisible by $20$ = $1000 - \frac{10000 - 20}{20} + 1 =1000-499=501$

Divisible by $10$ but not $4$ and $3$ at the same time : Divisible by $10$ - (divisible $12$ and $10$) = Divisible by $10$ divisible by $60$ = $1000 - \frac{9960 - 60}{60} + 1 =1000-166=834$

Then by inclusion exlusion = $667+501-834 =334$

Hence = $1000-334 =666$

Comment: Thank you for answering me but can you explain a little more how did you get (9990-30)/30 and (10000-20)/20.

Comment: @krneki you are welcome ! As i wrote , i used Gauss formula such that ([(the biggest number that divisible by $30$) - (the smallsest divisible by 30) ] / 30 ) +1

Comment: @krneki it is very easy . how many term are there divisible by 3 in [3,15] ? Answer is 5. lets see it $\frac{15 - 3}{3} +1 = 4+1 =5$

Comment: @krneki formula for finding the number of terms in [a,b] divisible by  $k$ =( (the biggest number divisible by $k$ in $[a,b]$) - (the smallest number divisible by $k$ in $[a,b]$) / $k$ ) + $1$

Comment: ok i get it now, just one more thing the number 60 for example is just the smallest number that is divisible by 12 and 10.

Comment: @krneki lcm(12,10)=60 and the biggest number divisible by $60$ in $[1,10000]$ is $9960$ and the smallest is $60$ itself so apply the formula